# Stop Logstash process automatically after imported all data

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

**Situation:**

- I'm importing data to Elasticsearch via Logstash at 12 pm manually every day.
- I understand there is no "close" on Logstash because ideally, you would want to continuously send data to the server.
- I am using [elk-docker](https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io) as my ELK stack.
- I wrote a shell script that sends a command to a docker container to execute the following:

***dailyImport.sh***

```
docker exec -it $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME opt/logstash/bin/logstash --path.data /tmp/logstash/data -e \
'input {
    file {
        path => "'$OUTPUT_PATH'"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        mode => "read"
        file_completed_action => "delete"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["foo", "bar", "foo2", "bar2"]
    }

}

output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "foo"
        document_type => "foo"
    }
    stdout {}
}'
```

**What I have tried and understood:**

- I have read that adding `read` mode and `file_completed_action` to delete would stop the operation, I tried it but it didn't work.
- I would still need to send `Ctrl + C` manually to stop the pipeline. e.g:

```
^C[2019-02-21T15:49:07,787][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGINT received. Shutting down.
[2019-02-21T15:49:07,899][INFO ][filewatch.observingread  ] QUIT - closing all files and shutting down.
[2019-02-21T15:49:09,764][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6bdb92ea run>"}
Done
```

**I have read that I could do the following, but don't know how:**

- Monitor the sincedb file to check when Logstash has reached EOF, then kill Logstash.
- Use the stdin input instead. Logstash will shut down by itself when stdin has been closed and all inputs has been processed. On the flip side, it Logstash dies for whatever reason you don't know how much it has processed.

Reference: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/stop-logstash-after-processing-the-file/84959

**What I want:**

- I don't need a fancy progress bar to tell me how much data I have imported (against the input file).
- I only want to end the operation when "it's done" and maybe send a `Ctrl + C` when it reaches the EOF or "finished importing".

Answer (score 4):

for file input, in read mode, there's a way to exit the process upon reading all files, just set:

`input { file { exit_after_read => true } }`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-exit_after_read

Comment: However, `exit_after_read` does not work in all cases. See the [issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/288).

Answer (score 0):

How about running a script in the output of `dailyImport.sh` that keeps checking the expected data in Elasticsearch and then kill the Logstash process when it is done?

It is not too elegant but in [my case](https://medium.com/@quangdutran809/elasticsearch-docker-compose-with-pre-loaded-data-from-json-file-using-logstash-58e86ed6be05) it is just enough.

```
if curl 'http://eslasticsearch:9200/index/_count | grep -q "count: 100"; then
        #Kill Logstash service so container would stop
        kill $(ps aux | grep 'logstash' | awk '{print $2}')
        break
   else
        echo "Counting documents from Elasticsearch does not return the expected number. Retrying"
        sleep 2
   fi
```